# Running "Cloud Code" in php

Tags: php, scripting, cloud, backend, slim

I'm building a REST Api with SlimPHP with Admin UI. 
Via the UI i can change routes and database details.

I'm wondering if it is possible to add a function to run "cloud coud".
So basically, i want to be able to have a simple scripting language that can execute some functions for my routes and parameters.

For example my route would be

```
$app->get('/calc/:one/:two', function ($one, $two) {
     //execute logic defined in backend scripting language
});
```

In my Backend I want the opportuniy to have a textarea where I can define my logic in any kind of simple scripting language:

```
/*example script in JS*/
route.calc.logic = function(parameters){
var result = parameters.one * parameters.two;
return result;
}
```

Solutions I tried: php's eval() function - but it is way to complicated for my purposes and quiet insecure as well..

Comment: You are asking the wrong question (s) if Eval is your solution

Comment: that's why I don't want to use it and ask for your advice ;)